# Service Restarted with START_NOT_STICKY

Tags: android, service

I have a service that runs in the background.  It is fine if the system kills this service on low memory conditions, however, I do not want the service to be restarted by the system.

So in order to do this I return the START_NOT_STICKY flag from my onStartCommand as such:

```
    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {

        // do stuff here

        return START_NOT_STICKY;
    }
```

However, when I open a bunch of applications on purpose to create low memory conditions I see this in the logs:

```
    Process com.myapp (pid 3960) has died.
    Scheduling restart of crashed service com.myapp/.MyService in 5000ms
    Low Memory: No more background processes.
    ...
    Start proc com.myapp for service com.myapp/.MyService: pid=4905 uid=10031 gids={3003, 1015}
```

So my process IS being restarted when it shouldnt be.  Why is this?  According to the documentation START_NOT_STICKY should not allow the service to be restarted.  Is there any other way to prevent the restart of the service?   Or can I tell when my service has been restarted?

Thanks

Comment: Are you sure there are no pending intents that would start said service? If there are intents pending or if a intent that your service handles is fired, you'll still start.

Comment: There are no pending intents.  However, the service does have a couple of BroadcastReceivers...would that affect anything?

Comment: If a intent is fired for which a BroadcastReciver is registered (e.g. in the AndroidManifest.xml), the service will be fired up to handle it.

Comment: The BroadcastReceivers are not registered in the Manifest but within the service itself: registerReceiver(myReceiver, new IntentFilter(MY_ID));

Comment: I've removed all BroadcastReceivers and Listeners and still have the same issue.

Comment: Nick did you find why it was like that, fond any solution ? thanks

Comment: This [solution](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17768932/service-crashing-and-restarting) works for me as expected.

Answer (score 0):

Have you looked at the [IntentService](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/IntentService.html)? Starts, does what it needs to do, and then stops itself. I have better luck with it.

Comment: Unfortunately, that wont work for my case.  I need to keep the service running until the system decides it's time to kill it.

Answer (score 0):

There can be multiple reasons for restarting a service even though it is NOT_STICKY:

- If your service is bound, by using [bindService](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/android-developers/x4pYZcXeKsw/ltYoH42Bed0J) with BIND_AUTO_CREATE
- If you have pending intents on the Service

The best way to resolve this issue is by unbinding the service.