# Why does my Android service get restarted when the process is killed, even though I used START_NOT_STICKY?

Tags: android, android-service

My app uses a pattern where I start a service with [Context#startService()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context.html#startService%28android.content.Intent%29) as well as bind to it with [Context#bindService()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context.html#bindService%28android.content.Intent,%20android.content.ServiceConnection,%20int%29).  This is so that I can control the lifetime of the service independently from whether any clients are currently bound to it.  However, I noticed recently that whenever my app is killed by the system, it soon restarts any services that were running.  At this point the service will never be told to stop, and this is causing battery drain whenever it happens.  Here's a minimal example:

I found someone with a similar issue [here](https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups=#!topic/android-developers/x4pYZcXeKsw), but it wasn't ever diagnosed or solved.

Service:

```
@Override
public void onCreate() {
    Toast.makeText(this, "onCreate", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}

@Override
public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
    return START_NOT_STICKY;
}

@Override
public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
    return new Binder();
}
```

Activity:

```
@Override
protected void onStart() {
    super.onStart();
    Intent service = new Intent(this, BoundService.class);
    startService(service);
    bindService(service, mServiceConnection, 0);
}

@Override
protected void onStop() {
    unbindService(mServiceConnection);
    Toast.makeText(this, "unbindService", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    super.onStop();
}
```

To test it, I launched the app, which started the service and bound to it.  Then I backed out of the app, which unbinds (but leaves the service running).  Then I did

```
$ adb shell am kill com.tavianator.servicerestart
```

and sure enough, 5 seconds later, the "onCreate" toast appears, indicating that the service started again.  Logcat shows this:

```
$ adb logcat | grep BoundService
W/ActivityManager(  306): Scheduling restart of crashed service com.tavianator.servicerestart/.BoundService in 5000ms
I/ActivityManager(  306): Start proc com.tavianator.servicerestart for service com.tavianator.servicerestart/.BoundService: pid=20900 uid=10096 gids={1028}
```

If I replace the startService() pattern with BIND_AUTO_CREATE, the problem doesn't occur (even if I crash the app while it's still bound to the service).  It also works if I never bind to the service.  But the combination of start, bind, and unbind seems to never let my service die.

Using dumpsys before killing the app shows this:

```
$ adb shell dumpsys activity services com.tavianator.servicerestart
ACTIVITY MANAGER SERVICES (dumpsys activity services)
  Active services:
  * ServiceRecord{43099410 com.tavianator.servicerestart/.BoundService}
    intent={cmp=com.tavianator.servicerestart/.BoundService}
    packageName=com.tavianator.servicerestart
    processName=com.tavianator.servicerestart
    baseDir=/data/app/com.tavianator.servicerestart-2.apk
    dataDir=/data/data/com.tavianator.servicerestart
    app=ProcessRecord{424fb5c8 20473:com.tavianator.servicerestart/u0a96}
    createTime=-20s825ms lastActivity=-20s825ms
    executingStart=-5s0ms restartTime=-20s825ms
    startRequested=true stopIfKilled=true callStart=true lastStartId=1
    Bindings:
    * IntentBindRecord{42e5e7c0}:
      intent={cmp=com.tavianator.servicerestart/.BoundService}
      binder=android.os.BinderProxy@42aee778
      requested=true received=true hasBound=false doRebind=false
```

Comment: did you try to stop it from code? does this make a difference ?

Comment: Yes if it's already stopped then everything's fine.  But if the app gets killed between when I unbind and when I stop it, then it gets restarted.

Comment: The documentations says, if there is a pending Intent it will restart, so maybe when didn't unbind the service, puts it in pending status...

Comment: It does unbind the service though, and there is no pending intent because only one intent was ever sent to it, which started it in the first place.

Comment: have you tried to test if the input Intent is really null when the service is auto-restarted ?

PS:same issue here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9491258/service-restarted-with-start-not-sticky

Comment: adb shell am kill com.tavianator.servicerestart prints error message Error: Unknown command: kill

Comment: @buzeeg There is no input intent; onCreate() gets called but not onStartCommand().

Answer (score 32):

Look to this [document](http://android-developers.blogspot.com.au/2010/02/service-api-changes-starting-with.html) section: Service lifecycle changes (since 1.6)

updated

after some investigations (have created project, run described command step by step, etc)
i found that code is working exactly as described in "Service lifecycle changes"

what I found: 
`adb shell am kill com.tavianator.servicerestart` kills **nothing**

(try `adb shell` , then in shell `am kill com.tavianator.servicerestart` 
You will be faced with **error** message `Error: Unknown command: kill`)

so,

run your application, 

run `adb shell`

in shell run `ps` command

find PID number of Your app 

in shell run command `kill <app_xx_PID>` 

where  is Your PID number 

repeat killing steps for service (if it is running in its own process)

check if service is running (should not), restarted after 5-7 sec

 **update**

 one solution (not enough good, but usable in some cases) is `stopSelf()` e.g.:

```
@Override
public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
    Toast.makeText(this, "onStartCommand", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    stopSelf();
    return START_NOT_STICKY;
}
```

**update**

updated solution

```
void writeState(int state) {
    Editor editor = getSharedPreferences("serviceStart", MODE_MULTI_PROCESS)
            .edit();
    editor.clear();
    editor.putInt("normalStart", state);
    editor.commit();
}

int getState() {
    return getApplicationContext().getSharedPreferences("serviceStart",
            MODE_MULTI_PROCESS).getInt("normalStart", 1);
}

@Override
public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
    if (getState() == 0) {
        writeState(1);
        stopSelf();
    } else {
        writeState(0);
        Toast.makeText(this, "onStartCommand", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
    return START_NOT_STICKY;
}
```

Why service get restrted when the process is killed?

According to this [document](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/services.html#Lifecycle):

> When a service is started, it has a lifecycle that's independent of
>   the component that started it   and the service can run in the
>   background indefinitely, even if the component that started it is
>   destroyed. As such, **the service should stop itself when its job is
>   done by calling stopSelf()**, or another component can stop it by
>   calling **stopService()**. 
> **Caution**: It's important that your
>   application stops its services when it's done working, to avoid
>   wasting system resources and consuming battery power. If necessary,
>   other components can stop the service by calling stopService(). Even
>   if you enable binding for the service, you must always stop the
>   service yourself *if it ever received* a call to *onStartCommand()*

from other hand document says:

> *START_NOT_STICKY* - If the system kills the service after onStartCommand() returns, do not recreate the service, unless there
>   are pending intents to deliver. This is the safest option to avoid
>   running your service when not necessary and when your application can
>   simply restart any unfinished jobs.

So, after reading this document and some experiments i think system treats manually killed services as unfinished (crashed: @see `W/ActivityManager(306): Scheduling restart of crashed service`) and restarts it despite of value returned by onStartCommand.

stopSelf() or stopService() - **no restarts**, why not if job done ?

Comment: At least point out the essential part. Remember that he used `START_NOT_STICKY`

Comment: From that document, "START_NOT_STICKY says that, after returning from onStartCreated(), if the process is killed with no remaining start commands to deliver, then the service will be stopped instead of restarted."  However this is not happening.

Comment: Regarding your edited answer, "am kill <package>" works fine on my phone.  Maybe it depends on the phone?  Mine is a rooted Galaxy Nexus.

Anyway, calling stopSelf() in onStartCommand() will stop the service right away, right?  Or at least immediately after it's unbound, which won't work for me.

Comment: I`ve tested on emu and on GT-I9003, not rooted

Comment: While the workaround you just posted will certainly work, the services being recreated still causes the process to be loaded, and my Application's onCreate() to run, which I'd like to avoid.

Comment: MODE_MULTI_PROCESS is deprecated in SDK23 and above.

Comment: A simpler way to kill a service is to select the service process name in the Logcat window in the IDE and then click the stop application button.

Answer (score 10):

I believe the problem here is that for a Service that was started by calling `startService()`, the internal accounting for its bindings (affected by calls to `bindService()`/`unbindService()`) are somehow preventing the service to be brought down correctly after it is scheduled for restart when the process is killed.

Depending on your preference, it seems that there are three alternatives to avoid this issue (you mentioned the first two already in your question):

- Use `startService()`/`stopService()` only, do not use `bindService()`/`unbindService()` at all.
- Use `bindService()`/`unbindService()` only (with `BIND_AUTO_CREATE`), do not use `startService()`/`stopService()` at all.
- If you need `startService()`/`stopService()` **and** `bindService()`/`unbindService()`, override the [`onUnbind()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Service.html#onUnbind%28android.content.Intent%29) method in your service and call `stopSelf()` from it:

  ```
  @Override
  public boolean onUnbind(Intent intent) {
      stopSelf();
      return super.onUnbind(intent);
  }
  ```

From my testing:

- Using the first alternative will print this line in the log:

  > W/ActivityManager(  nnn): Scheduling restart of crashed service xxxx in 5000ms

  but the service will not be really restarted after that.
- The second alternative will cause your service to be destroyed after you unbind (in the Activity's `onStop()` in your example).
- The third alternative will basically make your code behave like the second alternative (without needing to change it by much).

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 2):

How about reconsidering your **pattern**?

The START_NOT_STICKY flag appeared at some point during Android evolution (after 1.6?). Most probably, you are facing some subtle regression in service life cycle, which was introduced at that time.  So, even if an equally subtle solution is found for now - and magically verified to work on all possible devices - it will not necessarily work under new Android versions.

Anyway, that life cycle pattern looks unusual, and that might be the very reason for your running into this exotic problem.

Let's consider two cases.

1. Normal (?).  Some activity starts the service.  Soon after that it gets bound, used, unbound - then what? Stopped somehow?  How come there's no significant battery drain in this case?
2. Abnormal.  Service killed at some (random?) point.  When restarted, it implements some wrong assumption and stays active, doing something that drains the battery?

It all looks rather strange.

I would analyze the concurrent processes in your product.  All significant cases.  Some diagrams, etc.  Most probably, as a result, the very need for such a pattern would be eliminated.

Otherwise, it looks like any workaround will be a fragile hack.