# Android process is bad error on killing the app

Tags: android, android-service, android-sensors

Here is the exact error

```
02-08 12:36:43.490 3479-4980/? W/ActivityManager: Scheduling restart of crashed service com.wfl/.StepTrackerShakeDetectorService in 1000ms

02-08 12:36:44.494 3479-3513/? W/ActivityManager: Unable to launch app com.wfl/10139 for service Intent { cmp=com.wfl/.StepTrackerShakeDetectorService }: process is bad
```

Here is the scenario
It is basically a step tracker

> **StepTrackerShakeDetectorService** is implemented to restart automatically when app is destroyed using START_STICKY

But when the app is removed from task list I am getting this error.

Here is the code.

```
public class StepTrackerShakeDetectorService extends Service {

    private SensorManager mSensorManager;
    private StepTrackerShakeDetector mShakeDetector;
    private Sensor step_counter_sensor;
    private Sensor step_detector_sensor;
    private Sensor step_accelerometer;

    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {

        registerDetector();
    }


    private void registerDetector() {

        mSensorManager = (SensorManager) getSystemService(Context.SENSOR_SERVICE);

        step_counter_sensor = mSensorManager.getDefaultSensor(Sensor.TYPE_STEP_COUNTER);
        step_detector_sensor = mSensorManager.getDefaultSensor(Sensor.TYPE_STEP_DETECTOR);
        step_accelerometer = mSensorManager.getDefaultSensor(Sensor.TYPE_ACCELEROMETER);

        if (step_counter_sensor != null) // sensor not supported
        {
            mShakeDetector = new StepTrackerShakeDetector(Sensor.TYPE_STEP_COUNTER);
            mSensorManager.registerListener(mShakeDetector, step_counter_sensor, SensorManager.SENSOR_DELAY_FASTEST);
        } else if (step_accelerometer != null) {

            mShakeDetector = new StepTrackerShakeDetector(Sensor.TYPE_ACCELEROMETER);
            mSensorManager.registerListener(mShakeDetector, step_accelerometer, SensorManager.SENSOR_DELAY_FASTEST);
        }


        mShakeDetector.setOnShakeListener(new StepTrackerShakeDetector.OnShakeListener() {

            @Override
            public void onShake(int count) {
              //Code to calculate steps
            }
        });
    }

    private void unregisterDetector() {
        mSensorManager.unregisterListener(mShakeDetector);
    }

    @Override
    public void onStart(Intent intent, int startId) {
        super.onStart(intent, startId);
    }

    @Override
    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
        return START_STICKY;
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        unregisterDetector();
        super.onDestroy();
    }

    @Override
    public void onTaskRemoved(Intent rootIntent) {
        super.onTaskRemoved(rootIntent);
        Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), StepTrackerShakeDetectorService.class);
        PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getService(this, 1, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_ONE_SHOT);
        AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
        alarmManager.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, SystemClock.elapsedRealtime() + 2000, pendingIntent);
    }


}
```

**Here is the error in lenovo phab 2**

```
02-13 11:42:12.211 975-1964/? W/ActivityManager: Scheduling restart of crashed service com.wfl/.StepTrackerShakeDetectorService in 1000ms
02-13 11:42:12.213 975-1964/? I/ActivityManager:   Force stopping service ServiceRecord{7a45ff2 u0 com.wfl/.StepTrackerShakeDetectorService}
02-13 11:42:12.214 975-1964/? V/ActivityManager: Broadcast: Intent { act=android.intent.action.PACKAGE_RESTARTED dat=package:com.wfl flg=0x10 (has extras) } ordered=false userid=0 callerApp=null
02-13 11:42:12.216 975-2003/? W/ActivityManager: Spurious death for ProcessRecord{2325a63 0:com.wfl/u0a146}, curProc for 30626: null
02-13 11:42:12.790 2342-2361/? D/GasService: FG app changed: from com.wfl to
```

Comment: I'm wondering why your app crashed in the first place. If that reason still persists it's going to crash again. Can we see the code to the Service?

Comment: Kindly share code and logcat

Comment: Updated the question with code

Comment: Try START_NOT_STICKY

Comment: No START_NOT_STICKY does not work  @SahilManchanda

Comment: Are you running the Service in a separate process? If you don't override `onTaskRemoved` does your Service restart automatically? It should do. Also, related open bounty question? https://stackoverflow.com/q/48615198/1256219

Comment: No I am running the service in same process. In some devices it does not restart if I don't override onTaskRemoved

Answer (score 0):

Put this line at the end of the function in `onTaskRemoved`

```
        super.onTaskRemoved(rootIntent);
```

Comment: Is it coming only a particular device?

Comment: The first error from one plus devices and the error in the last is from lenovo phab 2. In some devices like moto, samsung it is working fine

Answer (score 0):

Change your onbind method which returns null to

```
@Override
public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
    return new Binder();
}
```

and run again if not working please see the below links

[Why does my Android service get restarted when the process is killed, even though I used START_NOT_STICKY?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12648447/why-does-my-android-service-get-restarted-when-the-process-is-killed-even-thoug)

In the below link, one is using the same procedure to get **alarm services and the others services in back ground** check this out also

[Service crashing and restarting](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17768932/service-crashing-and-restarting#18199749)